# Metamask Swap contract logic

Tags: metamask

Currently I am studying about metamask swap contract.

I am not sure if I understood the process right.

If I am swapping 1ETH to DAI

1. From my wallet, 1ETH is transferred to Contract `0x881d40237659c251811cec9c364ef91dc08d300c` (metamask swap router)
2. Metamask swap router has 4 internal transactions
3. 1 ETH is transferred to `0x74de5d4FCbf63E00296fd95d33236B9794016631` (metamask router 2)
4. Router 2 divides 1 ETH to 0.00875ETH (metamask swap fee), 0.99125 (swap amount)
5. Router 2 sends metamask swap fee to `0xF326e4dE8F66A0BDC0970b79E0924e33c79f1915` (MetaMask: DS Proxy), swap amount to swap aggregation router (ex. 1inch)
6. Swap aggregation router swaps 0.99125 ETH to DAI and sends back to my wallet

Is this process right? I would be very thankful for any help.